# Problems linking Nlopt-2.4.2 in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, nlopt

Some back story: I am trying to [get the bolt-lmm software](https://data.broadinstitute.org/alkesgroup/BOLT-LMM/) to compile on a Windows machine, because it would be a nice addition to the research group I am in. The developers of the software have only made a linux static executeable, but made the source code available. I am used to programming in R or python, and this is my first ever encounter with C++.

I have solved a fair bit of problems, but for some reason I have not been able to get visual studio to link properly with `Nlopt-2.4.2`.

I [downloaded it](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_on_Windows/)
and followed the steps given there on how to install it.

I can tell I have done the same to link the Nlopt library to the project as is described in [How to add additional libraries to Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project)

I still get errors like:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__nlopt_create referenced in function "public: __thiscall nlopt::opt::opt(enum nlopt::algorithm,unsigned int)" (??0opt@nlopt@@QAE@W4algorithm@1@I@Z)    boltCompiler    C:\Users\au483192\source\repos\boltCompiled\boltCompiler\NonlinearOptMulti.obj  1
```

(there are a total of 12 of this type of error, and an error link 1120, which just tells me there are 12 unresolved eternals.)

I hope this is enough information to provide a hint of what is going wrong.

Comment: can you please share include statement of nlopt file.

Answer (score 1):

I did some more digging, and it seems the linker needed more than just the folder for the .lib file.

This post sums it up:
[Linking a static library to my project on Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049640/linking-a-static-library-to-my-project-on-visual-studio-2010?rq=1)

Essentially you just need to tell the linker the placement of the lib and the actual name of the .lib file.

Hopefully this will help others who forgot/did not know that added library names manually could be needed for some libraries.

TL;DR: 
open configuration properties for the project > linker > general
Then add the path to the .lib file in the "addition library directories" line

Then (still in configuration properties) go to linker > input 
add the .lib file name to the "addition dependencies" line, e.g. libnlopt-0.lib (don't forget to separate with ";")